# combine stick-table with url pattern

Tags: haproxy

Is it possible to setup a `http-request deny` rule as a combination of `http_req_rate` and some non static URL pattern?

```
frontend myfrontend
  stick-table type binary len 20  size 100k  expire 10s  store http_req_rate(10s)
  http-request track-sc0 src

  http-request set-var(txn.url_prefix) path,field(2,/)

  http-request deny if { sc_http_req_rate(0) gt 1000 }
```

I'd like to count requests for URL prefixes (like `var(txn.url_prefix)` above) and combine aforementioned `http-request deny` with this counter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading thoroughly [Bot Protection with HAProxy](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/bot-protection-with-haproxy/) I could elaborate a solution by myself.

```
frontend myfrontend
  stick-table type binary size 1m expire 5m store gpc0,gpc0_rate(30s)
  http-request track-sc0 path,field(2,/)
  http-request sc-inc-gpc0(0)

  # optionally configure variables for logging purpose
  # http-request set-var(req.path_field2) path,field(2,/)
  # http-request capture var(req.path_field2) len 100
  # http-request set-var(req.gpc0_rate) sc_gpc0_rate(0)
  # http-request capture var(req.gpc0_rate) len 10
```